# Why is my URI not supported? FileInfo Argumentexception

Tags: c#, exception, ftp, uri, fileinfo

I'm very confused about my code right now. I have a CarPhoto Object and in that object is a PhotoList list. In that list is a link to a photo, which is located on my FTP server.

When I try to delete the file, I get this message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: URI formats are not supported.

Here's the code:

```
private void delete_Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Wilt u deze foto echt verwijderen?", "Foto verwijderen", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        int index = imageLinkList.SelectedIndex;
        CarPhoto photo = car.PhotoList[index];
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(photo.Photolink); //The exception gets thrown here.The link is: http://pqrojectqars.herobo.com/Images/Fiat/Punto/Wit/40.jpg
        string extension = fi.Extension;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `FileInfo` describes a file which is on your local machine or a UNC. It can't describe a remote file sitting on your FTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I already found a solution. The FTP answers you guys are giving me was already in the code, I just had to find the extension of the file. it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect to the FTP server using a FTP library to delete the file.

`FileInfo` does not know about FTP.

Answer (score 0):

`FileInfo` will work only for local files or files sitting on a UNC:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The specified path can also refer to a relative path or a Universal
>   Naming Convention (UNC) path for a server and share name

What you *can* do is execute a `FtpWebRequest` to execute a file deletion:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}",response.StatusDescription);  
}
```